# Get Value From Specific Column In foreach Loop

Tags: php

I have a query and I loop through its results to display the records inside a table, and this is working fine.

My table has 5 columns: RecID, Name, Feedback, Score, and Product.

As you can see the loop below will list all 5 columns. What I would like to do is only list 4 of the columns: Name, Feedback, Score, and Product, but store the RecID into a variable called `$RecID`.  Then I will use the $RecID in the Delete link to call the Ajax function to delete the record based on the ID.

How can I exclude a specific column in the display and also capture the  RecID value to store in a variable `$RecID`?

```
<?php
    while($dataArray = mysql_fetch_array($queryexe, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
        echo "<tr>\n";
        foreach ($dataArray as $col_value) {

            echo "\t<td>$col_value</td>\n";
        }
        //echo "<td><a onclick('deleteRecord(" + $recID + ")'>Delete</a></td>";
        echo "</tr>\n";
    }
?>
```

Comment: $col_value['column_name']

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use a loop to show the columns, just access the fields you want directly using `$dataArray['colname']`.

```
<?php
while($dataArray = mysql_fetch_array($queryexe, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    echo "<tr>\n";
    echo "<td>{$dataArray['Name']}</td><td>{$dataArray['Feedback']}</td><td>{$dataArray['Score']}</td><td>{$dataArray['Product']}</td>";
    echo "<td><a onclick('deleteRecord({$dataArray['RecID']})'>Delete</a></td>";
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your `foreach` loop to get the column name as well as its value. Then, inside the loop, you can check for the specific column name you want and process it differently than the others.

```
while($dataArray = mysql_fetch_array($queryexe, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<tr>\n";
    foreach ($dataArray as $col_name => $col_value) {
        if ($col_name == 'RecID') {
            echo "<td><a onclick('deleteRecord(" . $col_value . ")'>Delete</a></td>";
        } else {
            echo "\t<td>$col_value</td>\n";
        }
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
```

You can read about the differences between the two different syntaxes for `foreach` and how they should be used in the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

Comment: this method works too, so thank you.  However, I have a tough time to align the Delete link to be the last column.  Any suggestion?

Comment: The other answer is better for this than using a foreach loop, because you do not have to depend on the order of the columns in your query.